# Communication between Linux Containers (lxc)

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, lxc

I have a container for my Apache webserver, and another one for my Mysql server. I have given them 2 static IPs

```
NAME                   STATE    IPV4        IPV6  AUTOSTART  
-----------------------------------------------------------
apache                 RUNNING  10.0.3.10   -     YES        
mysql                  RUNNING  10.0.3.20   -     YES
```

The problem I have is that I can't seem to reach the Mysql server from the Apache server.

If I run this on the mysql server:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

I have no problem logging in, but if I run this on the web server:

```
mysql -h 10.0.3.20 -u root -p
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.3.20' (111)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So how are you ip addresses set up between host and both containers? do the containers "know" each other?

Comment: As I already said, I gave to each container a **static ip**. If they know each other, is what I am asking for. Probably not, since they cant seem to communicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with containers but with mysql configuration. By default mysql listens on localhost only. You need to change it to `0.0.0.0` bind address.

E.g. before change you can see 127.0.0.1:3306. It should be 0.0.0.0:3306

```
root@mysql:~# netstat -anp |grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      418/mysqld   

edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

edit the bind-address line to look like this:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Then restart mysql service.

Connect to mysql in the mysql container and create the root@"all" user with the below command.

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'; flush privileges;

Remember: replace PASSWORD with a root password for root@all that you want to have

Comment: Although in this specific question it probably does not matter, I would firewall the mysql port. `sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.3.10 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT ; sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REJECT` or use ufw ;)